# Matlab - How to get rid of edge artifact appearing around contour plot

Tags: matlab, mesh, contour, colormap, contourf

I am facing a problem with the `contourf` function.

Here is my code, which is part of a gui (hence the handles):

```
contourLevels = (1:0.5:60);
axes(handles.firstcontouraxes);
contourf(Y,fliplr(X),z1, contourLevels,'edgecolor','none'); 
axis equal
colormap(cmap);
colorbar();
title('Paramater a plot');
set(gca,'TickDir','out','box','off');
```

Yielding the following plot:

[image: contour plot]

As you can see, there is a red edge at the interface between the sample and air (air is when the value is 0 and appear white).

I suspect that `contourf` is trying to smooth my data, as the white area (air) is made of 0s and then we suddenly have relatively larger values at the sample-air interface.

Is it possible to remove this feature?

Comment: Make the white `NaN` or remove the interpolation (`shading flat` I think).

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with some arbitrary values that can be shared in your question?

Comment: _the white area (air) is made of 0s_ => according to the colorbar, isn't zero black?

Comment: @Person.Woman.Man.Camera.TV - I am starting from 1 (as can be seen in "contourLevels = (1:0.5:60);". Its quite complicated to reproduce as it is a gui, but will try and share if I could.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, Thank you.  Replacing the 0 with NaN fixed the problem. Shading flat did not have an effect